Query custom fields in rally, fetch not working with underscore for custom field
I'm building custom apps in rally for dashboards, and I'm running into an issue querying for custom fields. When using fetch, the underscore in the name of the custom field is throwing an error. If I remove the custom field from the query, all works as expected.
queryConfigs[1] = { type : 'defect',
                key  : 'defects',
                fetch: 'ObjectID,FormattedID,Name,Owner,UserName,DisplayName,ScheduleState,c_AccessibilityDefect',
                query: queryCriteria.replace('_ITER_TARGET_', targetIterationName),
                order: 'FormattedID'
            };

c_AccessibilityDefect is the problem child, throwing the following error in the console:
InvalidQueryError: Invalid characters in fetch attribute
